# adding value for map which is key of other map in DART

Tags: dart

I have a map like this,

```
"data":{ 
      "date":"Date",
      "time":"Time",
      "from":"From",
      "to":"To",
      "color":"Color",
      "state":"State",
      "country":"Country"
   },
```

I want to create another map that should look like this,
map header;
which should contain,

```
header {
"1":"date",
"2":"time",
"3":"from",
"4":"to",
"5":"color",
"6":"state",
"7":"country",
}
```

I am not getting how to add the key of another map as a value to header map, and also adding key starts form 1.

can anyone help me on this
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dart, you can do something like this.

```
var header = data.keys.toList().asMap().map((index, value)=> MapEntry(index+1, value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to achieve that:

```dart
var i = 1;
Map.fromIterable(data.keys, key: (_) => i++);
```